# How to get data from first day of the month until yesterday

Tags: oracle, date

does anyone know the query to get data from first day of the month until yesterday? I Try using query below but the problem is when today is the first day of the month, so the value become between 20170201 and 20170131

```
 select * from a where to_char(DATE,'yyyymmdd') BETWEEN to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm')||'01' and to_char(sysdate-1,'yyyymmdd')
```

Ex: if today is 01-02-2017 i want to select the data from 01-01-2017 until 31-01-2017, but if today is 13-02-2017 i want to select the data from 01-02-2017 until 12-02-2017, thank's before

Comment: For a start, you are doing "character arithmetic"; you should be doing date arithmetic.

Comment: What should happen in this edge case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been updated with your new logic.  The query below will retain records under the following conditions:

- `someDate` falls between the first day and yesterday of the current month, or
- `someDate`, when today is the first of the month, falls anywhere in the previous month

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE someDate BETWEEN CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) = 1
                            THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-1, 'MONTH')
                            ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE,   'MONTH') END AND
                       CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) = 1
                            THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 1
                            ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) END
```

This query assumes that you have a `DATE` column called `someDate`.

Comment: sorry sir, I think my question is wrong, i have edited my question, but this is useful too, thanks